App Script to create copies of sheets based off their URLS and name them with information typed into a cell
I am wanting to create a google sheet with URLs to multiple different sheets templates and a box to enter a name and a “create” button. This button would make copies of all sheets using the URLS listed and add the name entered in a cell to the beginning of the new sheet’s name (ex. “Template Sheet” would become “Name - Template sheet”)
I have tried having all the template sheets into the same sheets at the button and it works but some of the templates need to populate multiple pages into 1 sheets and that’s not the case
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RUXBL3sMcnt87r6-6Zo892oWgrJXmlKmNLfXitja3II/edit?gid=0#gid=0
Here is the current google sheet with linked templated that should all be copied into new documents using the name entered to name the new copies, the drive url link to store the new copies, and the email to share access to newly create documents. The current app script is to copy existing sheets in the same spreadsheet which doesnt format properly. Bonus points if I could get it to only create the documents that have checked checkboxes.
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // get your google spreadsheet app environment
const users = ss.getSheetByName('create'); // get the user sheet

function onOpen(){
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
   .addItem('Create New Docs','makeNewSheets')
   .addItem('Clear History','clearContent')
  .addToUi()
}

function clearContent() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('DocHistory');

  range.clearContent();
}

function makeNewSheets() {
  const source = ss.getSheetByName('roster');
  const r = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  //console.log(r)
  const sheetToCopy = ss.getSheetByName('Timelog');
  

  r.forEach(function (row) {
    if (row[0]) {
      const newSheetName = row[0] + " - Timelog";
      const userEmail = row[1];
      const newSheetUrl = SpreadsheetApp.create(newSheetName).getUrl();
      const newSheetID = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newSheetUrl).getId();
      const nextSheetNameSpace = users.getRange(users.getLastRow()+1,1).getA1Notation();
      const nextUrlSpace = users.getRange(users.getLastRow()+1,2).getA1Notation();
      const folderID = ss.getSheetByName('create').getRange('B3').getValue();
      const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
      const file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSheetID);
      file.moveTo(folder)
      file.addEditor(userEmail)

      users.getRange(nextUrlSpace).setValue(newSheetUrl);
      users.getRange(nextSheetNameSpace).setValue(newSheetName);

      const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newSheetUrl);
      sheetToCopy.copyTo(newSheet);
      newSheet.deleteSheet(newSheet.getSheetByName(`Sheet1`));
      newSheet.getSheetByName(`Copy of Timelog`).setName('Timelog');
   

    }

  })

  const p = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  //console.log(r)
  const sheetToCopy2 = ss.getSheetByName('Follow Up Tracker');

  p.forEach(function (row) {
    if (row[0]) {
      const newSheetName = row[0] + " - Follow Up Tracker";
      const userEmail = row[1];
      const newSheetUrl = SpreadsheetApp.create(newSheetName).getUrl();
      const newSheetID = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newSheetUrl).getId();
      const nextSheetNameSpace = users.getRange(users.getLastRow()+1,1).getA1Notation();
      const nextUrlSpace = users.getRange(users.getLastRow()+1,2).getA1Notation();
      const folderID = ss.getSheetByName('create').getRange('B3').getValue();
      const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
      const file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSheetID);
      file.moveTo(folder)
      file.addEditor(userEmail)

      users.getRange(nextUrlSpace).setValue(newSheetUrl);
      users.getRange(nextSheetNameSpace).setValue(newSheetName);

      const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newSheetUrl);
      sheetToCopy2.copyTo(newSheet);
      newSheet.deleteSheet(newSheet.getSheetByName(`Sheet1`));
      newSheet.getSheetByName(`Copy of Follow Up Tracker`).setName('Follow Up Tracker');
   

    }

  })

  const q = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  //console.log(r)
  const sheetToCopy3 = ss.getSheetByName('1 1 Report');

  q.forEach(function (row) {
    if (row[0]) {
      const newSheetName = row[0] + " - 1:1 Report";
      const userEmail = row[1];
      const newSheetUrl = SpreadsheetApp.create(newSheetName).getUrl();
      const newSheetID = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newSheetUrl).getId();
      const nextSheetNameSpace = users.getRange(users.getLastRow()+1,1).getA1Notation();
      const nextUrlSpace = users.getRange(users.getLastRow()+1,2).getA1Notation();
      const folderID = ss.getSheetByName('create').getRange('B3').getValue();
      const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
      const file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSheetID);
      file.moveTo(folder)
      file.addEditor(userEmail)

      users.getRange(nextUrlSpace).setValue(newSheetUrl);
      users.getRange(nextSheetNameSpace).setValue(newSheetName);

      const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newSheetUrl);
      sheetToCopy3.copyTo(newSheet);
      newSheet.deleteSheet(newSheet.getSheetByName(`Sheet1`));
      newSheet.getSheetByName(`Copy of 1 1 Report`).setName('Report');
   

    }

  })

  const t = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  //console.log(r)
  const sheetToCopy4 = ss.getSheetByName('Training');

  t.forEach(function (row) {
    if (row[0]) {
      const newSheetName = row[0] + " - Training";
      const userEmail = row[1];
      const newSheetUrl = SpreadsheetApp.create(newSheetName).getUrl();
      const newSheetID = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newSheetUrl).getId();
      const nextSheetNameSpace = users.getRange(users.getLastRow()+1,1).getA1Notation();
      const nextUrlSpace = users.getRange(users.getLastRow()+1,2).getA1Notation();
      const folderID = ss.getSheetByName('create').getRange('B3').getValue();
      const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
      const file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSheetID);
      file.moveTo(folder)
      file.addEditor(userEmail)

      users.getRange(nextUrlSpace).setValue(newSheetUrl);
      users.getRange(nextSheetNameSpace).setValue(newSheetName);

      const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newSheetUrl);
      sheetToCopy4.copyTo(newSheet);
      newSheet.deleteSheet(newSheet.getSheetByName(`Sheet1`));
      newSheet.getSheetByName(`Copy of Training`).setName('Training');
   

    }

  })



}


Can you provide more clarity with your desired result, photos are acceptable just for the community to have better overview about your project.

I don’t have any photos but essentially a document that employee templates can be created for each new employee and have their name as the sheet name. I have 4 different document templates that would need to be generated

There are four templates. You have written a script that works for "some" of the four templates. 1) Would you please edit the question to include the sheet layout and script for copying those templates. 2) The question appears to concern only those templates [that] need to populate multiple pages into 1 sheets. Would you provide an explanation/demonstration of what this means, and include an example of the expected outcome for such templates.

I have updated the question to include link to google sheet and all templates as well as my current script

The spreadsheet and script have been added (thank you), but there is quite a bit of assumed knowledge. For example, populating Cells A3, B3, A5, B5 ("create"), "roster" is empty, and "Timelog" doesn't exist. You said that this script works; if so, you need to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Also, the meaning and significance of some of the templates need to populate multiple pages into 1 sheets has not been explained. Would you please supply an MRE and explain the issue with multiple sheets => 1 sheet.

Regarding "Timelog", I understand now; but this means that the names of the Templates in "create" are different to the script.

The templates were in that current spreadsheet and that worked to create seperate sheet copies but the problem I ran into once I got that working is that the follow up tracker has 3 sheets within the spreadsheet. Due to the templates being mulitple sheets on the 'create docs' spreadsheet it wasnt creating it with all 3 pages needed. Here is the link to the current working version: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16QjtI_NeInK9jYv8EEPAk73jZY9s63TgvJRjocpJHI4/edit?gid=0#gid=0

I think the “new” approach makes sense (create copies of four separate files). The only proviso being: do you expect the new employee folder to contain four separate spreadsheets/files or one consolidated file/spreadsheet?

I'm aiming to have the new employee docs to be 4 separate spreadsheets/files. Thats where I got stuck was creating 4 separate spreadsheets from templates outside of the 'create doc' spreadsheet.

You want to make copies of certain template files (identified by a checked checkbox) for a given employee and saved to a given Drive Folder.
Consider this answer, based on the OP script:

Column C contains checkboxes
Column D contains a linked Template file name
Column E contains the relevant Template file ID. Column E can be hidden.
Cells: "A3","B3","A5","B5" contain relevant employee information
The user checks the Column C boxes that are required for this employee.
Run the function from the Custom menu

tests for all employee data fields.
loops through the checkbox fields testing for "true". if "true"

create a new file name
copy the template ID to the new file name in the specified drive folder.






h/t @Tanaike for the simplified 2-line "copy" script from Saving a copy of a sheet to a specific folder

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // get your google spreadsheet app environment
const users = ss.getSheetByName('create'); // get the user sheet

function onOpen(){
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Create New Docs','buildTemplates')
  .addToUi()
}

function buildTemplates() {  

  var empFieldRange = ["A3","B3","A5","B5"]
  var empFieldData = empFieldRange.map(f => users.getRange(f).getValue())
  var empFieldDataLength = empFieldRange.map(f => users.getRange(f).getValue().length)
  //Logger.log(empFieldData) // DEBUG
  //Logger.log(empFieldDataLength) // DEBUG
  //Logger.log("field data includes zero: "+empFieldDataLength.includes(0)) // DEBUG

  // test for length=0 on any of the Drive/Employee fields.
  if (empFieldDataLength.includes(0) == true)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Data missing from 'Drive/Employee fields'. \nProcessing cancelled; please check all four fields.")
    return
  }

  // all Employee data fields are populated.
  // keep processing

  // get checkbox, Template Name and Template ID values
  var checkRangeValues = users.getRange("C2:E5").getValues()
  // Logger.log(checkRangeValues)  // DEBUG

  // loop through the checkbox values
  for (var i=0;i<checkRangeValues.length;i++){
    var checkboxValue = checkRangeValues[i][0]
    if (checkboxValue != true){
      // checkbox is false, do nothing
      // Logger.log("i:"+i+",  checkbox = "+checkboxValue) // DEBUG
      continue
    }

    // check box is checked, so make a copy of the  file
    var templateName = checkRangeValues[i][1]
    var templateId = checkRangeValues[i][2]
    var newFilename = empFieldData[2]+" - "+templateName
    // Logger.log("i:"+i+",  checkbox = "+checkboxValue+", file name = "+templateName+", ID: "+templateId+", new file name: "+newFilename) // DEBUG
    
    var specificFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(empFieldData[1])
    var copiedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy(newFilename, specificFolder);
    var newFileID = copiedFile.getId()
    // Logger.log("the file id of the copied template file is: "+newFileID) // DEBUG
  }
}


SAMPLE


I am getting this error after entering my drive URL, I cant figure out why....
"Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp."

More information is required (and feel free to do your own troubleshooting). 1) Cell A3 contains URL for the Drive folder in which the employee's new files will be saved. Is this correct? 2) Is the DriveURL entered accurately? 3) Cell B3 contains a formula that extracts the ID from the DriveURL. Is the ID complete and correct? 4) In the script, does empFieldRange identify the correct cell locations? 4) In the script, what is the value of empFieldData[1] (this should be the folderID)? 5) How is the function being triggered? 6) Is the Folder a shared folder?
